# Interpreting beta coefficients in a regression model when fixing covariates

Tags: python, r, regression, logistic

Suppose I am interested in studying the effect of pizza on mortality across a number of countries.

```
y = Death [1/0]  
x1 = Pizza [1/0]  
x2 = Country [Italy/Germany/France]
```

In a logistic regression model, *Country* gets one-hot encoded so the model is:

`y = b0 + b1 * Pizza + b2 * Italy + b3 * Germany + b4 * France`

I'm interested to know how `OddsRatio(b1)` changes in Italy (vs. Germany and France). How should I proceed? Do I subset data to only Italy and rerun the LR model?

e.g. If I'm interested in Italy only, the model evaluates to `y = b0 + b1 * Pizza + b2* Italy` but this only provides the odds of death in Italy.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Unfortunately, this model is not identifiable: it has too many parameters.  The question itself is difficult to comprehend: what do you suppose is inducing any change in the odds ratio for Pizza?  What does it mean to compare Italy to Germany and France simultaneously?  Perhaps reading some of our [threads on interpreting odds ratios](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpret+odds+ratio) will answer your question or at least help you clarify it.

Comment: @whuber Why can't you evaluate the odds as if everyone was Italian and then divide by the odds as if there is a mix of Italian and German using the shares from the data?

Comment: @dimitriy I can't answer that, because I can't figure out the question.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I believe the response below addressed what I'm ultimately trying to solve. The option was to either (a) run a model with interaction effects or (b) run a model for EACH unique country (which would be tedious). I'm positive that the OR(Pizza) would be different for each country if I proceeded with (b) which prompted my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused how mortality is a binary outcome... it sounds like you are leaving out some details about your data. That being said, it sounds like you're interested in whether the effect of pizza differs between countries. This is an interaction hypothesis, so something like: (note that if country is dummy coded then one level is left out - i.e. France is implicitly when Italy and Germany both =0).

```
y = b0 + b1 * Pizza + b2 * Italy + b3 * Germany + b4 * Pizza*Italy + b5 * Pizza*Germany
```

You would then evaluate the interaction effect by comparing the model fit of the model with the two interactions to the model fit of the model without the two interactions.

Comment: This is it. Thank you! I needed that refresher on interaction effects. To confirm my understanding, in this new revised model, suppose b4 (Pizza and Italy) is not statistically significant, the effect of Pizza on Mortality in Italy is simply b1. OTOH, if b5 (Pizza and Germany) is statistically significant, then the effect of Pizza on Mortality in Germany is b3 + b5

Comment: To determine whether the countries differ you compare the two models - the one without interactions ('m1') and the one with ('m2'). For instance 'anova(m1,m2)' in R. If *that* is significant, then the countries differ, at which point you can ask what is driving the difference.

Comment: I believe what you're suggesting is important only if you want to confirm if the models are different or not. In my case, I'm only interested in understanding the change in OR of a covariate, conditioned on another covariate.

Comment: If the models aren't different, then any 'change' in the OR is noise.

Comment: The model is incorrect as written. You have a binary outcome on the left but the function for the log odds on the right. The discussion is about the effects on log odds rather than the odds the OP asked about.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that fitting separate models is fiddly, especially if you want to conduct statistical tests of the difference. But you don't necessarily need country $\times$ pizza interactions. They are already built into the model because of the nonlinearity. I would advise against putting in such interactions unless there is a good reason, like theory.

Your large model is

$$\ln \left(\frac{p}{1-p} \right) =  b_0 + b_1 \cdot Pizza + b_2 \cdot Italy + b_3 \cdot Germany + b_4 \cdot Pizza \cdot Italy + b_5 \cdot Pizza \cdot Germany,$$
where $p$ is the probability of death. Exponentiating both sides yields the odds:

$$odds = \frac{p}{1-p} =  \exp \{b_0 + b_1 \cdot Pizza + b_2 \cdot Italy + b_3 \cdot Germany + b_4 \cdot Pizza \cdot Italy + b_5 \cdot Pizza \cdot Germany \}.$$

This means the odds are still a function of the country and pizza consumption.

In France, it's

$$\exp \{b_0 + b_1 \cdot Pizza \}.$$

In Italy, it's $$\exp \{b_0 + b_1 \cdot Pizza + b_2 + b_4 \cdot Pizza \}.$$

In Germany, it's $$\exp \{b_0 + b_1 \cdot Pizza + b_3 + b_5 \cdot Pizza \}.$$

The country coefficients reflect systematic differences in mortality from nation-level factors like the quality of the healthcare systems and exercise habits. It seems sensible to include those. The country $\times$ pizza coefficients would capture country differences in the effect of pizza on mortality. Maybe the pizza in Italy and Germany is more or less lethal than the pizza in France, but that has to come from some hypothesis or theory. Are there killer differences in toppings across countries? Do they deep fry the pizza first in some countries? Seems unlikely. So why include these variables since you still get an interaction without them?

To see that, start with a simpler model without explicit interactions:
$$\ln \left(\frac{p'}{1-p'} \right) =  \tilde b_0 + \tilde b_1 \cdot Pizza + \tilde b_2 \cdot Italy + \tilde b_3 \cdot Germany.$$

I changed the coefficient names to reflect the simplified model.

The odds still depend on the country since there are country coefficients inside $\exp \{.\}$

In France, it's

$$\exp \{\tilde b_0 + \tilde b_1 \cdot Pizza \}.$$

In Italy, it's
$$\exp \{\tilde b_0 + \tilde b_1 \cdot Pizza + \tilde b_2 \}.$$

In Germany, it's  $$\exp \{\tilde b_0 + \tilde b_1 \cdot Pizza + \tilde b_3 \}.$$

This shows that the interactions are baked into the functional form.

So how can you compare the change in odds in Italy vs. Germany and France? One way is to multiply $\tilde b_3$ by the German population as a share of France and Germany from your survey instead of 1. Germany is slightly bigger than France, so that might be ~$0.55$. Then you would compare $$\exp \{\tilde b_0 + \tilde b_1 \cdot Pizza + \tilde b_2 \}$$ with $$\exp \{\tilde b_0 + \tilde b_1 \cdot Pizza + \tilde b_3\cdot 0.55 \}.$$ This compares the odds for an Italian versus a hybrid person whos a bit more German than French.

Perhaps that seems odd (pun intended). You can also do a weighted version. Since these are rates, you will need a weighted harmonic mean:

$$\frac{1}{\frac{0.55}{\exp \{\tilde b_0 + \tilde b_1 \cdot Pizza + \tilde b_3 \}} + \frac{0.45}{\exp \{\tilde b_0 + \tilde b_1 \cdot Pizza \}}}$$

Here's an illustration analogous to your pizza example. I model the probability that a car was made abroad as a function of price and three (arbitrary) MPG groups of unequal size (here, 1 is inefficient, 2 is OK, and 3 is efficient). The odds for the three methods look like this:

[image]

The weighted harmonic mean of the odds gives slightly higher odds than the hybrid of Groups 2 and 3. It makes sense that the low-MPG cars have very low odds of being foreign, at any price, compared to medium and high-efficiency automobiles. This was the 1970s. You can use these to construct odds ratios, but I did not do that here.

---

**Stata**

```
/* Clean Up Data and Get Weights*/
sysuse auto, clear
_pctile mpg, percentiles(30, 80, 90) 
egen mpg_group = cut(mpg), at(0, `=r(r1)', `=r(r2)', 100) icodes
replace mpg_group = mpg_group + 1
tab mpg_group
sum 2.mpg_group if mpg_group != 1, meanonly
scalar s2 = r(mean)
sum 3.mpg_group if mpg_group != 1, meanonly
scalar s3 = r(mean)

/* Main Logit Model Without Interactions */
logit foreign i.mpg_group c.price, nolog
estimates store logit

/* Weighted Harmonic Mean of Odds */
margins mpg_group, ///
at(price = (3000(2000)16000) ) ///
expression(predict(pr)/(1 - predict(pr))) post
forvalues i=1/7 {
    local lincom "`lincom' (price`=1000 + 2000*`i'':1/( scalar(s2)*_b[`i'._at#2.mpg_group]^(-1) + scalar(s3)*_b[`i'._at#3.mpg_group]^(-1) ))"
    local margins_coeff_rename "`margins_coeff_rename' `i'._at = `=1000 + 2000*`i''"
}

nlcom `lincom', post
estimates store lincom

/*  MPG Group 1 Odds */
estimates restore logit
margins, ///
at(mpg_group = 1 price = (3000(2000)16000)) ///
expression(predict(pr)/(1 - predict(pr))) post
estimates store margins_g1

/* Weighted Hybrid of MPG Group 2-3 Odds */
estimates restore logit
margins, ///
at(2.mpg_group = `=scalar(s2)' 3.mpg_group = `=scalar(s3)' price = (3000(2000)16000)) ///
expression(predict(pr)/(1 - predict(pr))) post
estimates store margins_g23

/* Compare Odds */
coefplot lincom margins_g23 margins_g1 ///
, vertical noci recast(connected) offset(0) /// 
rename(`margins_coeff_rename' price* = "") ///
title("Odds for Foreign to Domestic Varying Price by Group") ///
ytitle("Odds") xlab(, grid) ///
legend(order(2 "Odds for a Hybrid Mix of MPG Groups 2 & 3" 1 "Weighted HM of MPG Group 2 & 3 Odds"  3 "Odds for MPG Group 1") row(3)) ///
note("Frankenstein Mix and Weighted Average are 0% Group 1, `=round(scalar(s2)*100,1)'% Group 2, and `=round(scalar(s3)*100,1)'% Group 3")
```

Comment: Thanks for showing this work. The weighted approach was interesting and I'll consider it! Recall that I'm only interested in how b1 (Pizza) changes in different countries. If I was to consider the interaction model, is the below interpretation correct?

Effect of Pizza on Mortality in Italy is: b1*Pizza  + b2 + b4*Pizza

Comment: That's the log odds for Italy as a function of pizza. It's not an effect on mortality in the usual sense if the word, though you can get the effect of pizza on log odds from that by taking the derivative.